# onBlur event with selectize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using the selectize.js package in my application (https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) and i'm trying to cat the option selected by user using the onBlur event withou succeed. Bellow is a code as example:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.css" />
        <div class="demo">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="select-beast-single-disabled">Onblur:</label>
                <select id="select-beast-single-disabled" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select a person...">
                    <option value="">Select a person...</option>
                    <option value="1">Arnold</option>
                    <option value="2" selected>Nikola Tesla</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <script>
                $('#select-beast-single-disabled').selectize({
                    create: true,
                    sortField: {field: 'text'},
                        onBlur: function () {

                            input = document.getElementById('select-beast-single-disabled');

                            console.log(input.value)

                        }
                });
            </script>
        </div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Inspect select via console
2. Select "Arnold"
3. In console, the console.log will print ""
4. Then, if you press again, will print 1

Expected result:

In the first time that we select the option, the selectize must "blur" the selectize and log the right option, no "".

Actual result:

We have to click twice on the same option to update the value in console.log with the right option.

Is there any workaround for it? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `onChange(value)` instead of `onBlur()`? Seems like that does exactly what you desire.

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.css" />
        <div class="demo">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="select-beast-single-disabled">Onblur:</label>
                <select id="select-beast-single-disabled" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select a person...">
                    <option value="">Select a person...</option>
                    <option value="1">Arnold</option>
                    <option value="2" selected>Nikola Tesla</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <script>
                // save select to variable
                var $select = $('#select-beast-single-disabled').selectize({
                    create: true,
                    sortField: {field: 'text'}
                });

                // fetch the instance
                var selectize = $select[0].selectize;

                // attach blur event
                selectize.on('blur', function onBlur() {
                    // get the value from selectize instance.
                    console.log(selectize.getValue());
                });

            </script>
        </div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried. The disadvantage of using the onChange event is that if a value is already selected, it will not fire until the user selects another option.

Comment: Allright, fair enough. Then I'd recommend saving the selectize instance to a variable and getting the value from there. see https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md and the "getValue()" method.

Comment: Please could you post here any code that does what you suggested?